# Can anybody give me an example of use the smallest_last_vertex_ordering in boost::graph?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I am new in boost programming, but i hope to use the boost graph lib on vertex coloring.

I have read the help doc and source code of smallest_last_vertex_ordering in boost/graph/smallest_last_ordering.hpp. But I don't know how to construct the parameters for function smallest_last_vertex_ordering.

Here is the definition of smallest_last_vertex_ordering:

```
template <class VertexListGraph, class Order, class Degree, class Marker>
  void 
  smallest_last_vertex_ordering(const VertexListGraph& G, Order order, 
                            Degree degree, Marker marker) {
    typedef typename boost::graph_traits<VertexListGraph> GraphTraits;
    typedef typename GraphTraits::vertex_descriptor Vertex;
    //typedef typename GraphTraits::size_type size_type;
    typedef std::size_t size_type;

    const size_type num = num_vertices(G);

    typedef typename boost::property_map<VertexListGraph, vertex_index_t>::type ID;
    typedef bucket_sorter<size_type, Vertex, Degree, ID> BucketSorter;

    BucketSorter degree_bucket_sorter(num, num, degree,  
                                  get(vertex_index,G));

    smallest_last_vertex_ordering(G, order, degree, marker, degree_bucket_sorter);
 }
```

Can you tell me how to create the right class of Order, degree and Marker?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the implementation `Order` seems to be a [property map](http://www.boost.org/libs/graph/doc/using_property_maps.html) that has std::size_t as key and a vertex_descriptor as value_type. `Degree` and `Marker` are property maps with vertex_descriptor as key and std::size_t as value_type. These last two maps are only needed internally and that is the reason why there is an overload with only two parameters (graph and order property map).

Here is an example using that overload and a directed version(to avoid loops that apparently are not supported by this algorithm) of the graph [here](http://www.boost.org/libs/graph/doc/sequential_vertex_coloring.html):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/shared_array_property_map.hpp> //this should be included from smallest_last_ordering.hpp
#include <boost/graph/smallest_last_ordering.hpp>

int main()
{
    typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS,boost::vecS,boost::directedS> Graph;
    typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor VertexDesc;

    Graph g;
    VertexDesc A=add_vertex(g);
    VertexDesc B=add_vertex(g);
    VertexDesc C=add_vertex(g);
    VertexDesc D=add_vertex(g);
    VertexDesc E=add_vertex(g);

    add_edge(A,C,g);
    add_edge(A,E,g);
    add_edge(C,B,g);
    add_edge(E,B,g);
    add_edge(C,D,g);
    add_edge(B,D,g);
    add_edge(E,D,g);

    boost::vector_property_map<VertexDesc> order;

    smallest_last_vertex_ordering(g, order);

    std::string names[]={"A","B","C","D","E"};

    for(std::size_t index=0; index<num_vertices(g); ++index)
    {
        std::cout << names[order[index]] <<  " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

and here is a version that uses the four parameter overload so you can see another way to define property maps:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/shared_array_property_map.hpp> //this should be included from smallest_last_ordering.hpp
#include <boost/graph/smallest_last_ordering.hpp>

int main()
{
    typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS,boost::vecS,boost::directedS> Graph;
    typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor VertexDesc;

    Graph g;
    VertexDesc A=add_vertex(g);
    VertexDesc B=add_vertex(g);
    VertexDesc C=add_vertex(g);
    VertexDesc D=add_vertex(g);
    VertexDesc E=add_vertex(g);

    add_edge(A,C,g);
    add_edge(A,E,g);
    add_edge(C,B,g);
    add_edge(E,B,g);
    add_edge(C,D,g);
    add_edge(B,D,g);
    add_edge(E,D,g);

    typedef std::map<std::size_t,VertexDesc> OrderMap;
    OrderMap order;
    boost::associative_property_map<OrderMap> order_prop_map(order);

    typedef std::map<VertexDesc,std::size_t> Map;
    Map degree;
    Map marker;
    boost::associative_property_map<Map> degree_prop_map(degree);
    boost::associative_property_map<Map> marker_prop_map(marker);

    smallest_last_vertex_ordering(g, order_prop_map, degree_prop_map, marker_prop_map);

    //another alternative
    // std::vector<VertexDesc> order(num_vertices(g));
    // std::vector<std::size_t> degree(num_vertices(g));
    // std::vector<std::size_t> marker(num_vertices(g));
    // smallest_last_vertex_ordering(g, make_iterator_property_map(&order[0],boost::identity_property_map()), make_iterator_property_map(&degree[0],get(boost::vertex_index,g)), make_iterator_property_map(&marker[0],get(boost::vertex_index,g)));

    std::string names[]={"A","B","C","D","E"};

    for(std::size_t index=0; index<num_vertices(g); ++index)
    {
        std::cout << names[order[index]] <<  "(" << degree[order[index]] << "," << marker[order[index]] << ") ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```